# possible side effect of siunitx, tgheroes, familydefault combination

Tags: fonts, siunitx

I use the following code to change the font to sans serif. I would like to use TeX Gyre Heroes and copied the code snipped from [tug.dk](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/tgheros/).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tgheros}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} %% Only if the base font of the document is to be sans serif
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

2 K, 2 Kelvin, \SI{2}{K}, \SI{2}{Kelvin}

\end{document}
```

However, the result is not as expected:

[image: all in effect]

The fonts are slightly different. Leaving the `\usepackage{tgheroes}` out leads to

[image: no_tgheroes]

which seems okay. Leaving the `\renewcommand...` out also seems to work, now with a serif font.

[image: no_renew]

Is this a side effect of a combination of all 3 (`siunitx`, `tgheroes`, `renew...`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declaring `\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}` doesn't change the `\mathsf` font; `siunitx` realizes that it's in a sans serif context and so uses `\mathsf`.

Add

```
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{OT1}{\sfdefault}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{bold}{OT1}{\sfdefault}{b}{n}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tgheros}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{OT1}{\sfdefault}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{bold}{OT1}{\sfdefault}{b}{n}

\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} %% Only if the base font of the document is to be sans serif

\begin{document}

2 K, 2 Kelvin, \SI{2}{K}, \SI{2}{Kelvin}

\bfseries
2 K, 2 Kelvin, \SI[detect-weight]{2}{K}, \SI[detect-weight]{2}{Kelvin}

\end{document}
```

The second line is just to see that the right font is chosen in the (unlikely) case you need `detect-weight`.

[image]

Alternatively, add the option `mode=text` (I wouldn't recommend it, though):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tgheros}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{mode=text}

\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} %% Only if the base font of the document is to be sans serif

\begin{document}

2 K, 2 Kelvin, \SI{2}{K}, \SI{2}{Kelvin}

\bfseries
2 K, 2 Kelvin, \SI[detect-weight]{2}{K}, \SI[detect-weight]{2}{Kelvin}

\end{document}
```